# what system is using on askubuntu.com website

Tags: discussion

I'm interested about " askubuntu.com " website construction.
Does anyone know what CMS " askubuntu.com " is using?

I tested so many A&Q website system before, but "askubuntu" is one of the best sites  for Answer and Question I have seen.

Answer (score 2):

There is a list answer on SO Meta that describes the benefits and disadvantages to many of the SO clones.

[Here is the specific question for which you are looking on SO Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score -1):

Check out:

[This site is for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about)